# ASP/VB debug function

Tags: debugging, vbscript, asp-classic

We are using ASP/VB on our webserver and we often include print statements to test things. Is it possible to make a debug function or sub that takes one argument (a string), and prints out that string with the linenumber from the caller?

Even a tip of how I could get a traceback should give me enough info to write this function, but I couldn't find such function.

Comment: You're talking about ASP Classic via VBScript, not ASP.Net, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just raise an error and let the debugger kick in.

```
Err.Raise 1, "Title", "Your Text"
```

Then either in an include or in a `500` error page you can use `Server.GetLastError()` to get the error which includes the [relevant information](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_ref_error.asp) such as `LineNumber` and `Source`.